# How to Include Complete Flutter Modules in Android AAR Artifact Library?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-module

I am working on creating an Android SDK module that includes a Flutter module. I have followed the instructions provided in the official Flutter documentation [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app/android/project-setup?tab=module-source) to integrate the Flutter module into my Android project.

```
setBinding(new Binding([gradle: this]))
evaluate(new File(                                                     
settingsDir.parentFile,                                            // new
'flutter_module/.android/include_flutter.groovy'                   // new
))                                                                     // new
```

I have also added the Flutter module as a dependency in my app/build.gradle file within my Android module.

```
implementation project(':flutter')
```

I have successfully integrated the Flutter module with a method channel, and it's working as expected.

Now, my challenge is in creating an AAR artifact library that includes the complete Flutter modules. When I generate the AAR artifact using the following Gradle code snippet, the sub-modules are not included in the library:

```
group = 'com.example.myAndroidSdk'
version = '1.0.0'


// Add sources as an artifact
task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier "source"
}


// Loop over all variants
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        // This creates a publication for each variant
        publishing.publications.create(variant.name, MavenPublication) {
            // The sources artifact from earlier
            artifact sourceJar

            // Variant dependent artifact, e.g. release, debug
            artifact source: output.outputFile, classifier: output.name

            // Go through all the dependencies for each variant and add them to the POM
            // file as dependencies
            pom.withXml {
                def dependencies = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

                // Filter out anything that's not an external dependency. You shouldn't
                // be publishing artifacts that depend on local (e.g. project) dependencies,
                // but who knows...
                configurations.getByName(variant.name + "CompileClasspath").allDependencies
                        .findAll { it instanceof ExternalDependency }
                        .each {
                            def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')

                            dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                            dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                            dependency.appendNode('version', it.version)
                        }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Ensure that the publish task depends on assembly
tasks.all { task ->
    if (task instanceof AbstractPublishToMaven) {
        task.dependsOn assemble
    }
}
```

How can I ensure that the complete Flutter modules are included in my Android AAR artifact? What modifications or additional steps do I need to take?

Comment: Did you see: https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app/android/project-setup?tab=android-archive#add-the-flutter-module-as-a-dependency

Comment: @MorrisonChang:I have integrated it following the steps outlined in this Flutter documentation link('https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app/android/project-setup?tab=android-archive#add-the-flutter-module-as-a-dependency'). I have also tried building the AAR using 'flutter build aar -v', but the sub dependencies are still not included.

Comment: It would probably help to describe in detail how your Flutter project is organized (dependencies & sub dependencies) and stating any errors/warning encountered when doing `flutter build aar`.  Possibly related: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39707